# How can i create 4 levels of sections

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to recreate the level system in these 2 images in my document 
[image: This level system]
I can't seem to create the one above because I don't know the command that created "Chapter 1"
[image: and this one]

I can't seem to create the one above because I don't know how to go beyond "subsubsection" so how is it possible to create a fourth level?

PS. I'm using `\documentclass[]{article}`

Comment: How about using e.g. a book document class, which has chapters?

Comment: @marmot can you show a small example of you recreating the above. because if it can then it might just be what im looking for

Comment: `\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Background}
\subsubsection{GUI}
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot I did not see your comment until I created my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For your next question, have a look at
>   [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)!

### Solution 1

Changing the number of numbered levels (down to `\paragraph`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\end{document}
```

You may have a look at the `titlesec` package if you want to change the formatting of the `\paragraph` heading level.

### Solution 2

Using a different document class (book) which provides an additional level (`\chapter`).

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: does this recreate the numbering system above? 
can you provide the compilation of the above with the same things I provided in my question, please?
note that all sections below chapter have to follow the same numbering as a chapter
please also note that my questions may seem rudimentary but that's because I've never used the document type book before.

Comment: @Zyzzx You can test it yourself :) (I do not have time now at the moment, but I am pretty sura that this is what you want). Normally you should provide the code that is necessary to reproduce your problem, have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: @Zyzzx The `book` class works exactly the same way as `article`, except you get the extra top level `\chapter` macro. For example you make a collection of articles into a book, just by dong something like `\chapter{one} \input article1.tex \chapter{two} \input article2.tex` etc.